# How to set User on controller property before Action method is accessed in .net core 1.1?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity

Using .net core 1.1 mvc

The objective is to restrict users so that they may only edit themselves, or allow admin to edit user. I need to get the current user and compare that user's id with the user id passed in an an argument (or cookie).

If the user ids don't match, check if the current user is an admin. If so, grab the user of the user id passed in as an argument (or cookie).

We have a controller that receives ApplicationDBContext and UserManager in the constructor via Dependency Injection.

I failed with both of these attempts:
1) I tried creating an ActionFilter which accessed UserManager through context.Controller.UserManager (a property I set from the controller constructor) but UserManager had an IDisposable error.

2) I tried doing this from the Controller constructor but I need to set the response to 404 if the user is not found and didnt know how to do that from outside of the Action method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a day of trial and error I figured it out and wanted to share since I could not find any examples online.

Note that I had to use IAsyncActionFilter because code execution would begin inside the Action method as soon as I called an async method in the filter (Controller.UserToEditProp = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync)

```
public class ImpersonateAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IAsyncActionFilter
{
    public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(
        ActionExecutingContext context,
        ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        string ThisUserID = context.HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
        ApiController Controller = (ApiController)context.Controller;
        var UserManager = Controller.UserManager;

        if (context.ActionArguments.ContainsKey("UserID"))
        {
            string RequestedUserID = context.ActionArguments["UserID"].ToString();

            if (ThisUserID != RequestedUserID)
            {
                if (!context.HttpContext.User.IsInRole(UserType.Admin.GetDisplayName()))
                {
                    context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
                }
            }

            Controller.UserToEditProp = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(RequestedUserID);
        }
        else
        {
            Controller.UserToEditProp = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(ThisUserID);
        }

        await next();

        // do something after the action executes
    }

}
```